# Pushing a button towards right-bottom on a page

Tags: html, button, haml

The following code pushes a button to the right, but it's not pushing it to the bottom of the page. Is there any way to do it (without using CSS preferrably):

Haml file:

```
%button(style="float: right; padding: 5px; margin: 0; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial.....)
```

Answer (score 0):

if your html is like this

```
<div class="outer">
  <button type="button" class="inner-button">Click Here</button>
</div>
```

you can write CSS to make it appear at the bottom right corner always like this

```
.outer {
  position: relative;
}
.inner-button{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  /*Any other CSS related to button*/
}
```

this will keep the button always at the right bottom of the page.

Hope this helps!